# メンバーのメールアカウントをLDAPで管理したい

Tags: centos, openldap

メンバーのメールアカウントをLDAP (OpenLDAP 2.4) で管理したいと考えております。
前提は簡単なもので下記になります。

---

目的：メンバーのメールアカウントをLDAPで管理したい

会社名：メールシステム

部署：営業部
部署：開発部

社員：営業部メールアドレスAさん
社員：営業部メールアドレスBさん

社員：開発部メールアドレスCさん
社員：開発部メールアドレスDさん

ドメイン名：local

※あとはデフォルトの設定でよい

---

この場合に `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf` に下記のような記述をこころみたのですが、
エントリの追加時にうまくいっていないようなので、
まず、設定ファイルが正しい記述かどうかお聞きしたく思います。
なにか記述的におかしいところはありますでしょうか。

お手数ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

**設定ファイル**

```
#
# See slapd.conf(5) for details on configuration options.
# This file should NOT be world readable.
#

include         /etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/duaconf.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/java.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/collective.schema

# Allow LDAPv2 client connections.  This is NOT the default.
allow bind_v2

# Do not enable referrals until AFTER you have a working directory
# service AND an understanding of referrals.
#referral       ldap://root.openldap.org

pidfile         /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile        /var/run/openldap/slapd.args

# Load dynamic backend modules
# - modulepath is architecture dependent value (32/64-bit system)
# - back_sql.la overlay requires openldap-server-sql package
# - dyngroup.la and dynlist.la cannot be used at the same time

# modulepath /usr/lib/openldap
# modulepath /usr/lib64/openldap

# moduleload accesslog.la
# moduleload auditlog.la
# moduleload back_sql.la
# moduleload chain.la
# moduleload collect.la
# moduleload constraint.la
# moduleload dds.la
# moduleload deref.la
# moduleload dyngroup.la
# moduleload dynlist.la
# moduleload memberof.la
# moduleload pbind.la
# moduleload pcache.la
# moduleload ppolicy.la
# moduleload refint.la
# moduleload retcode.la
# moduleload rwm.la
# moduleload seqmod.la
# moduleload smbk5pwd.la
# moduleload sssvlv.la
# moduleload syncprov.la
# moduleload translucent.la
# moduleload unique.la
# moduleload valsort.la

# The next three lines allow use of TLS for encrypting connections using a
# dummy test certificate which you can generate by running
# /usr/libexec/openldap/generate-server-cert.sh. Your client software may balk
# at self-signed certificates, however.
#TLSCACertificatePath /etc/openldap/certs
#TLSCertificateFile "\"OpenLDAP Server\""
#TLSCertificateKeyFile /etc/openldap/certs/password

# Sample security restrictions
#       Require integrity protection (prevent hijacking)
#       Require 112-bit (3DES or better) encryption for updates
#       Require 63-bit encryption for simple bind
# security ssf=1 update_ssf=112 simple_bind=64

# Sample access control policy:
#       Root DSE: allow anyone to read it
#       Subschema (sub)entry DSE: allow anyone to read it
#       Other DSEs:
#               Allow self write access
#               Allow authenticated users read access
#               Allow anonymous users to authenticate
#       Directives needed to implement policy:
# access to dn.base="" by * read
# access to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
# access to *
#       by self write
#       by users read
#       by anonymous auth
#
# if no access controls are present, the default policy
# allows anyone and everyone to read anything but restricts
# updates to rootdn.  (e.g., "access to * by * read")
#
# rootdn can always read and write EVERYTHING!

# userPasswordに関するアクセス権
#access to attrs=userPassword
#    by self write
#    by dn="cn=Manager,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local" write
#    by anonymous auth
#    by * none

# その他の属性に対するアクセス権
#access to *
#    by self write
#    by dn="cn=Manager,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local" write
#    by * read


# enable on-the-fly configuration (cn=config)
database config
access to *
        by dn.exact="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage
        by * none

# enable server status monitoring (cn=monitor)
database monitor
access to *
        by dn.exact="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" read
        by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local" read
        by * none

#######################################################################
# database definitions
#######################################################################

database        bdb
suffix          "dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local"
checkpoint      1024 15
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local"

# Cleartext passwords, especially for the rootdn, should
# be avoided.  See slappasswd(8) and slapd.conf(5) for details.
# Use of strong authentication encouraged.
# rootpw                secret
rootpw          {SSHA}l/GvSQdgXLNiQzEuIJkD92cTziZUIuwO

# The database directory MUST exist prior to running slapd AND
# should only be accessible by the slapd and slap tools.
# Mode 700 recommended.
directory       /var/lib/ldap

# Indices to maintain for this database
index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub

# Replicas of this database
#replogfile /var/lib/ldap/openldap-master-replog
#replica host=ldap-1.example.com:389 starttls=critical
#     bindmethod=sasl saslmech=GSSAPI
#     authcId=host/ldap-master.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

Comment: 設定ファイルで何を追記したのか、何を変更したのか、OpenLDAPのバージョンも明記されると回答がつきやすいと思います。

Comment: @A-pZ さん
ご指摘ありがとうございます。
Openldapの2.4になります。

Comment: @bird 追加情報はコメントへの返信ではなく質問を編集して追記してください